# Replicate Production Django Database to Local Foreman Server

Tags: django, heroku, foreman, django-database

I would like to have a local copy of the data in the Django database to facilitate offline development.  The production version is hosted by Heroku; the data is stored in a Postgres database and I am using foreman locally with the default mysqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done by exporting a backup from Heroku's pgbackup application, which can be done either through your dashboard or by going to your repo's root directory and running the following:

```
$ heroku pg:backups capture   # to capture snapshot of current db
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url`
```

You now have a Postgres dump file that can populate from an empty db on your local Postgres server. Most simply is to use PGAdmin and Load From Restore.

More info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

Comment: I am using the sqlite DB locally but certainly turning up a Postgres DB on my laptop might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Django REST framework and get each object using requests.  At this point the data can be inserted into the local copy using the object create method.